# jquery scroll to function except special link

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollto

here is the code and [link](http://jsfiddle.net/33qr5yuj/)

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on("click", function() {
    var target = $($(this).attr("href") );
    if(target.length) {
     $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 500);
   }
});
```

a simple scroll to function, sometime when click #top will not scroll to top completely, maybe other function made delay on top section, i try `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "500");` that work perfect, and i have two question

1. if i need #top dont effect on this function, how to check the href="#" not #top?
2. i need click #top and then do this `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "500");`, not `scrollTop: target.offset().top` of the function, any simple way to do this?

thanks so much

Comment: You mean you want to scrollTop to the top of the body when you click on "top" instead of the top of the `#top` div ?

Comment: yes, because sometime other function effect made some lag, scroll top by #top not completely, but use $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "500"); work perfect, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if href is not equal to '#top'. You can do something like this

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on("click", function() {
    var target = $($(this).attr("href") );
    if(target.length && $(this).attr("href") != '#top') {
     $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 500);
    }else{
     $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500);
    }
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/33qr5yuj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jquery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) plugin, here's how:

```
<!-- Include jQuery from somewhere, must use version 1.8 or above -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include latest jquery.scrollTo, currently 2.1.0, can download from https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/releases -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.scrollto/2.1.0/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<!-- Initialize the scroll on click, this can go in a js file instead of inline of course -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  // You can avoid the document.ready if you put the script at the bottom of the page
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {
      // Prevent the jump and the #hash from appearing on the address bar
      e.preventDefault();
      // Scroll the window, stop any previous animation, stop on user manual scroll
      // Check https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo for more customizability
      var dest = this.hash === '#top' ? 0 : this.hash;
      $(window).stop(true).scrollTo(dest, {duration:1000, interrupt:true});
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

That should help you implement it.